# how to fit my entire html file in a single window

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, scrollbar

How to fit my entire html file in a single window and get rid of the scroll bar. (In other words: how to minimize the html file to show entire content in one window).

I tried adding width = "100" but that is throwing an error.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=%(charset)s" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">%(styles)s
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    %(table)s%(legend)s
</body>

</html>"""

_styles = """
        table.diff {font-family:Courier; border:medium;}
        .diff_header {background-color:#e0e0e0}
        td.diff_header {text-align:right}
        .diff_next {background-color:#E6E6FA}
        .diff_add {background-color:#aaffaa}
        .diff_chg {background-color:#ffff77}
        .diff_sub {background-color:#ffaaaa}"""

_table_template = """
    <table class="diff" id="difflib_chg_%(prefix)s_top" 
           cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rules="groups" >
        <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup>
        <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup>
        %(header_row)s
        <tbody>
%(data_rows)s        </tbody>
    </table>"""

_legend = """
    <table class="diff" summary="Legends">
        <tr> <th colspan="2"> Legends </th> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <table border="" summary="Colors">
                      <tr><th> Colors </th> </tr>
                      <tr><td class="diff_add">&nbsp;Added&nbsp;</td></tr>
                      <tr><td class="diff_chg">Changed</td> </tr>
                      <tr><td class="diff_sub">Deleted</td> </tr>
                  </table></td>
             <td> <table border="" summary="Links">
                      <tr><th colspan="2"> Links </th> </tr>
                      <tr><td>(f)irst change</td> </tr>
                      <tr><td>(n)ext change</td> </tr>
                      <tr><td>(t)op</td> </tr>
                  </table></td> </tr>
    </table>"""
```

Image: 
[HTML output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4RF2.jpg)

Comment: In general, images of code are not helpful (http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and in this case they're also not sufficient to replicate your issue. Ideally, questions should include a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem encountered.

Comment: Hi, I have deleted the code image and added the code. Now can you please check it and help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to make your body to 100% of window by doing:

CSS:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden; /* to hide scrollbar */
}
```

And also, i guess you have to add css in your tables as "width:100%" or according to how you want to display those two tables.